# ObservableCollection created from database table not updating

Tags: c#, .net, events, observablecollection

In my database helper class I set up the connection, create Table and ObservableCollection objects and handle all database operations:

```
public class ProfilesSourceSQLite : IProfilesSource
{
    private Table<ProfileManager.Profile> Profiles;
    private ObservableCollection<ProfileManager.Profile> profilesCollection;

    public ProfilesSourceSQLite()
    {
        ...
        Profiles = dbContext.GetTable<ProfileManager.Profile>();
        profilesCollection = new ObservableCollection<ProfileManager.Profile>(Profiles);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ProfileManager.Profile> GetProfilesCollection()
    {
        return profilesCollection;
    }

    public bool AddProfile(ProfileManager.Profile profile)
    {
        try
        {
            Profiles.InsertOnSubmit(profile);
            dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `CollectionChanged` event of `profilesCollection` is never triggered.

```
public class ProfileManager
{
    private static ProfileManager instance;
    public static ProfileManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ProfileManager();

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private ProfileManager()
    {
        ...
        profiles = new ProfilesSourceSQLite();
        profiles.GetProfilesCollection().CollectionChanged += ProfileManager_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void ProfileManager_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // MessageBox never appears
        MessageBox.Show("CHANGED!");
    }

    public bool AddProfile(Profile profile)
    {
        return profiles.AddProfile(profile);
    }
}

// Somewhere in the UI class
private void btnClicked()
{
    ProfileManager.Instance.AddProfile(newProfile);
}
```

I want to make `profilesCollection` to be `ItemsSource` of `ListView` so I don't have to care about handling items list changes but it also doesn't work as this simpler example. What am I doing wrong? Or is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the error that by adding to the database that the `ObservableCollection<ProfileManager.Profile>` will automatically update. It won't.

When you call `new ObservableCollection<ProfileManager.Profile>(Profiles);` it creates a snapshot of the profiles in the database. It does not create any link to the database so future database updates are not replicated to the collection.

So the code `Profiles.InsertOnSubmit(profile); dbContext.SubmitChanges();` does not update the collection. Hence it isn't raising the event.

Comment: So I totally misunderstood `ObservableCollection`. Thanks for clear explanation. Is there any object that can "watch" `Table<>` or I have to write all the events stuff myself?

Comment: You have to watch all of the events yourself. The `ObservableCollection<>` is something you can observe - it doesn't observe its source.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing an item in the collection, not the collection itself.
You need to make `ProfileManager.Profile` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to make your requirements.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I am changing collection. I insert new item to database.

Comment: You are changing the `Profiles` collection, not your `ObservableCollection`. You just use `Profiles` to initialize it.